# fast lane install .app on the simulator to run automation on travis

Tags: travis-ci, fastlane

I'm new to fast lane and trying to configure it on travis. 
I want to install the .app file on the simulator and open it. (I'm doing this to run appium tests on travis)

Can you please let me know how to achieve this using fastlane on travis?

**My current fastFile looks like this,**

```
lane :test do
 scan(scheme: "MyScheme")
end
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you have a `.travis.yml`, does it run your fastlane lane, does that throw some error?

Comment: I don't have any error. The default config for scan just runs the tests. I need it to install it on a simulator and open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gym(
  scheme: "SchemeName" ,
  configuration: "ConfigurationName",
  clean: true,
  workspace: "WorkSpaceName.xcworkspace",
  output_directory: "../output_directory",
  output_name: "IPA_Name.ipa",
  xcargs: "ARCHIVE=YES" # Used to tell the Fabric run script to upload dSYM file
)

open -a Simulator
xcrun simctl install booted ../output_directory/IPA_Name.ipa
```

Comment: Do Simulator can install IPA file? I think IPA is for real iPhone only.